# how to set elem with position:fixed on top stack order

Tags: css

How I can do this. Set div#6 with position:fixed z-index:6 stack on div#1 with z-index:5. See in  [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/A2xht/259/)

Comment: div#6 has z-index of 3, is that what you meant?

Comment: take out div#6 out of div#3 and assign div#6 z-index of 6 . It will work good.

Comment: @ovokuro fogot I set to 6 still not working.

Comment: @SahilDhir in real case div#6 must be in div#3 :(

Comment: so this will be the final html structure you are going to follow?

Comment: yes. will have many case like this

Comment: Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/09/Stacking-Changes-Coming-to-position-fixed-elements) We cant do anything. I have a trick to keep the parent to be a non-tag html. Cause [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Understanding_CSS_z-index%2FThe_stacking_context) a stacking context is formed. So avoid it

Comment: You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A2xht/262/)